# How can I find and remove forbidden characters in a filename?

Tags: file-management, copy-paste

In Windows, I often use copying a piece of text into notepad as a way of removing special characters that can cause trouble. This became a much more urgent problem in Android six months or so ago, when Android started rejecting any effort to rename a file that contained one or more forbidden printing or non-printing characters such as a colon or a carriage return. This change was not accompanied by any change to indicate what or where the problem character is.

Since I often try to rename PDF files with the real name of the document, copied from within the document, this has been a huge inconvenience. Is there any android text editing spp that removes or renders visible illegal characters as notepad does? Or has anyone found a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Use [`mv`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) / [`sed`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) or [`detox`](https://github.com/dharple/detox) or [`convmv`](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/) on any terminal emulator app. Btw a file cannot exist with "forbidden" characters in its name. They should be just "bad" characters; difficult to handle with common filesystem utilities or difficult to perceive.

Comment: I learnt to do it with SED years ago, I vaguely recall doing it with macro's